# Trimming text in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file which has a text formatted like that:

```
Timeticks: (243749689) 28 days, 5:04:56.89
OID: .1.3.6.1
STRING: "07/10/14 - 16:36:50"
Hex-STRING: 09 15
INTEGER: 2
STRING: "STR:/storage0/Alarm/process/2/sentence xxxx"
STRING: "storage0"
STRING: "23250002"
STRING: "4039209"
INTEGER: 0
IpAddress: 172.17.1.41
STRING: "public"
OID: .1.3.6.1
```

I am trying to trim that information but i can't get that done.

I need to get the information trimmed like that:

```
Date: 07/10/14 - 16:36:50
Process: process
Priority: 2
Sentence: sentence xxxx
Comunity: public
```

I am trying to star it like that:

```
    foreach my $x (@varbinds)
    {
            next if ($x =~ /^Timeticks:/);
            next if ($x =~ /^OID:/);
            next if ($x =~ /^Hex-STRING:/);
            printf OUTPUT_FILE "%s\n", $x->[1];
    }
```

Can someone give me a hand?

---

**Update**

This is my structure

```
my (@varbinds) = @{$_[1]};

unless (sysopen(OUTPUT_FILE, $SNMPTrapperFile, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND|O_CREAT, 0666))

foreach my $x (@varbinds) {
  next if ($x->[1] =~ m/Timeticks/);
  next if ($x->[1] =~ m/Integer/);
  if ($x->[1] =~ /^STRING/) {
    printf OUTPUT_FILE "%s\n", $x->[1];
  }
}

close (OUTPUT_FILE);
```

Correct, and that is giving me that output:

```
08/10/14 - 12:10:20
STR:/storage0/Alarm/process/2/sentence xxxx"
storage0
23250002
4065151
public
```

using that structure of the foreach, how could i format?

Comment: Instead of parsing output from SNMP command line utilities, why not use the [`SNMP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SNMP) or [`Net::SNMP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP) module?

Comment: how would that be done?

Comment: So the information that you want is always in the first, second, and sixth lines marked `STRING`? Is that the best way to select it? Do you want to process multiple blocks like that from a single file, or is there only ever a single collection of data in a file?

Comment: Correct.. i need the information as you said. and lets consider that there is only a single collection of data in the file.

Comment: I didn't know until I read the comment from `@ThisSuitIsBlackNot` that the text you are processing is output from a command-line utility. It is an essential part of any question to describe the *source* of your input data. The comment has a link to the documentation for both of the modules that are recommended. I suggest you try the examples in that documentation and ask another question if you are still struggling.

Comment: Re. "how would that be done?" Start by reading the documentation I linked to in my comment. `SNMP` is simply a front-end for the Net-SNMP library, while `Net::SNMP` is a pure-Perl implementation. They both offer similar functionality, although `SNMP` has some nifty functions for parsing MIB files. Either one will be much more robust than writing your own parsing logic from scratch.

Comment: The only thing is that I only have access to the file with the information.. I can't trim the information from the start. It has to be treated once is written to the file.

Comment: Why? Where does the file come from?

Comment: Theres a script which gets the trap and generates the file. and I only have access to that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that reads all of the information from the `DATA` file handle and processes it as a single chunk. It expects to find only a single set of data in the file, and that the lines of interest are the first, second, and sixth lines that begin with `STRING:`. Subsidiary information is taken from the *last three* fields of the *second* such line when it is split on slash characters `/`.

If you wish to read from a specific file that is specified on the command line, then you should read using `<>` instead of `<DATA>`. If you want to hard-code the path to a file then you need to make a call to `open`, like this

```
open my $fh, '<', 'myfile';
```

and read from it using the file handle that `open` creates, using `<$fh>` instead of `<DATA>`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $data = do {
  local $/;
  <DATA>;
};

my @strings = $data =~ /^STRING\s*:\s*"([^"]*)/mg;
my @fields = split qr|/|, $strings[1];

printf "Date: %s\n",      $strings[0];
printf "Process: %s\n",   $fields[-3];
printf "Priority: %s\n",  $fields[-2];
printf "Sentence: %s\n",  $fields[-1];
printf "Community: %s\n", $strings[5];

__DATA__
Timeticks: (243749689) 28 days, 5:04:56.89
OID: .1.3.6.1
STRING: "07/10/14 - 16:36:50"
Hex-STRING: 09 15
INTEGER: 2
STRING: "STR:/storage0/Alarm/process/2/sentence xxxx"
STRING: "storage0"
STRING: "23250002"
STRING: "4039209"
INTEGER: 0
IpAddress: 172.17.1.41
STRING: "public"
OID: .1.3.6.1
```

**output**

```
Date: 07/10/14 - 16:36:50
Process: process
Priority: 2
Sentence: sentence xxxx
Comunity: public
```

Comment: Borodin, this gave me a tip... but look how is my structure:

Comment: my (@varbinds) = @{$_[1]};
unless (sysopen(OUTPUT_FILE, $SNMPTrapperFile, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND|O_CREAT, 0666))
foreach my $x (@varbinds)
{
    next if ($x->[1] =~ m/Timeticks/);
    next if ($x->[1] =~ m/Integer/);
    if ($x->[1] =~ /^STRING/) {
  printf OUTPUT_FILE "%s\n", $x->[1];
    }
}
close (OUTPUT_FILE);

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado: What you have posted isn't valid Perl, and I don't see what point you're making about why my solution won't work. I have copied it into your question where it belongs. Please edit it to correct it, and explain what else you need.